# Binance API: status: 400, error code: -1013, error message: Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER

Tags: python, cryptography, binance, cryptocurrency

`status: 400, error code: -1013, error message: Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER`

I am trying to create a new order to sell all `SCRT` that are on my account and I cannot figure out what is the problem.

The filters for `SCRTBUSD` are:

```
{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00100000', 'maxPrice': '1000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00100000'}
```

The code I am using:

```
client = Spot(key=key, secret=secret)

account = client.account()
for asset in account['balances']:
    if asset['asset'] == 'SCRT':
        quantity = asset['free']
        break

# price = client.ticker_price('SCRTBUSD')['price']
price = client.avg_price('SCRTBUSD')['price']

params = {
        "symbol": 'SCRTBUSD',
        "side": "SELL",
        "type": "LIMIT",
        "timeInForce": "GTC",
        "quantity": quantity,
        "price": round(float(price) * float(quantity), 8)
    }

try:
    response = client.new_order(**params)
except ClientError as error:
    print(f"Found error. status: {error.status_code}, error code: {error.error_code}, error message: {error.error_message}")
```

The final price (`round(float(price) * float(quantity), 8)`) is `30.68230251`.

I have also thought that maybe by "price" they mean a price for 1 `BUSD` and I put the `"price": float(price)` and I have got the same error.

I tried both avg_price and ticker_price. Any ideas on how to set the right price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tickSize` for `SCRTBUSD` is: 0.001.

Therefore, you have to round the quantity to the next 0.001. For example:

```py
round(30.68230251, 3)
```

For more information about the `tickSize`, check the [exchangeInfo](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#exchange-information) on the Binance API documentation.